# Unable to SSH into Raspberry Pi 3 Model B headlessly

Tags: ssh, pi-3

A couple of days back, I connected my pi to my laptop using ethernet cable and was able to ssh into it using Putty. I found out the ip of my Pi by running the `ping raspberrypi.mshome.net` command on my windows cmd prompt, and then using that as an address to connect to my pi. Today however, I am unable to do the same. The set up is the same. I use a router and I have turned on the sharing network options of the wireless adaptor. I keep getting `request timed out`. I also cannot see the ip address of the pi when i run `arp /a` in windows. Could anybody help? I am a complete novice to Pi and have gone through the forums a bit but nothing works.

Comment: The setup is the same?  Why do you mention wireless if you are using a wired Ethernet connection?

Comment: it's bit tricky to use hostname when you ping on windows. The best way is to hook raspberry with display using hdmi and go to terminal and type ifconfig. Or you could use angry ip scanner to find out what is ur raspberry pi ip.

Comment: The wireless path was to inform that my laptop was connected to WiFi and I believe there is a need to enable sharing the network so the pi can be ssh'ed into. And unfortunately, i do not have a monitor with hdmi just VGA which is quite useless with pi. anyways, i rebooted the pc and the pi and now again it works, its really strange but now i am trying to set up a static ip for the pi so that i can bypass this stuff. should i mark this question as answered now?

Comment: If the Pi is connecting using the wireless adapter, it is using a different MAC address than the Ethernet port: your hostname resolution may not resolve properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By switching network interfaces you have switched DHCP leases, which in your case might have lead to a different (or missing) DNS name.

Alternatively, the Pi might be blocked from accessing the WiFi due to a missing or wrong encryption key (double check!).

I recommend using the `nmap` tool (from https://nmap.org). 
It's a universal networking tool for a multitude of purposes that belongs into every tinkerer's toolbox.

Assuming your Pi is configured for your WiFi and receives an IPv4 address in the range 192.168.1.x, the canonical way of probing a local network for running hosts is:

`sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24`

Substitute the actual address prefix according to your local setup, but keep the trailing zero befor the forward-slash.

You'll end up with a list of all host names and IPv4 addresses within your local network. Pick the RasPi's IPv4 from the vendor name.

The parameters `-sn` perform a special kind of probing that looks for running hosts and tries to find their names. 
See `man nmap` (or the online documentation) for a list of parameters and their meanings.

Answer (score 2):

One solution in Debian is to hardcode the IP address, which will be assigned to raspberry pi after every boot up. (Make sure, it has not been used by any other device).
After loading the image file, open the command.txt file and at the end of file add `IP=192.168.0.10` (your desired IP address, which has not been assigned to any other device in the network). Now each time at the bootup, this IP address will be assigned to the raspberry pi.
https://learnraspberrypi.wordpress.com/2016/05/15/headless-setup-of-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

Just download nmap on your home computer and see all the IP addresses on your network, and see your IP address.I hope that you have already plugged in your sd card to your Pi and start it once the green light is blinking already, hope you directly log in to pi, and I hope the SSH is already enabled, I guess it's default though it wasn't for me, it might be then download putty for windows and just use terminal for mac, and use the command after entering correct credentials for putty, and for mac use command ssh pi@ipaddrs, and substitute ipaddrs for the ip address